# Change the color on td in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I just want to change the color of td when when ever image get new tittle.

i'm just try this code but not able to find the tittle in image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code

```
self.setcolor = function () {
    $('#Census_Grid tr').each(function () {
        var customerId = $(this).find("#ErrorMessage").attr('data-toggle');
    });
}
```

Suggests to me that there are going to be multiple error messages in your table, if that is the case you will want to apply a class to those images not an id. You would then change that block to

```
self.setcolor = function () {
    $('#census_grid tr').each(function () {
        var customerId = $(this).find(".ErrorMessage").attr('data-toggle');
    });
}
```

If you otherwise want just the one error message as you currently have you can drop all that and just use.

```
self.setcolor = function () {
   var customerId = $("#ErrorMessage").attr('data-toggle');
}
```

As there is no need to find an id

Answer (score 0):

I see you defined the table with id `censusgrid`, but you call with `Census_Grid`, try using below code, hope this help :

```
$('#censusgrid tr').each(function () {
    var customerId = $(this).find("#ErrorMessage").attr('data-toggle');
});
```

Comment: can you post html structure of this line code `$('#Census_Grid tr')`

Comment: Your change is wrong, the selector should be `#ErrorMessage` not `ErrorMessage`. jQuery uses `#` to denote ID

Comment: @DGS lol.. oh my.. big mistake. How can i forgot that, 1st time in my life.That why receive down voted. Lol

Comment: weird, see this fiddle link  and look for the console, you got that data https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/pcptucn8/